# Error Sqoop using Oozie

Tags: jdbc, sqoop, oozie

I have a problem with a workflow oozie

I import a file using Sqoop with the command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@:ip:sid --username --password --target-dir
```

From the command line it works but scheduled in oozie gives me the error:

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

Why am getting this error?

Comment: It seems you don't have share/lib in your hdfs.

Comment: check hadoop logs for more details , oozie logs have very limited details

Answer (score 0):

Could you add more information to the question? How does oozie workflow.xml look like? 
I would guess that you don't have

```
<property> 
  <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
  <value>true</value> 
</property>
```

in your workflow.xml file which is resulting in sqoop jar not being found on the classpath. Add that to your workflow.xml and make sure your 
/user/oozie/share/lib/ 
has the sqoop jar. That should fix your issue.